Hot to get real time traffic information via CF api (for fast DDoS detection)
I'm fetching traffic data of my domains connected in CF using the code:
        $query = <<<'GRAPHQL'
        {
            viewer {
                zones(filter: {zoneTag: $zoneTag}) {
                    httpRequests1dGroups(limit: 100, orderBy: [date_ASC], filter: {
                        date_geq: $start, date_lt: $end
                    }) {
                        date: dimensions {
                            date
                        }
                        sum {
                            pageViews
                            requests
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
GRAPHQL;

        $variables = [
            'zoneTag' => $zoneTag,
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end,
        ];

        $json = json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables]);
        $curl = curl_init();
        $token = 'token-token'; // Read all accounts analytics and logs
        $url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql/";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $head[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        return $result;

This code was created to quickly find which domain is being DDoS'd (we have a lot of domains connected). The problem is that the data is refreshed with quite a long delay. Do you know how to obtain traffic data for a given domain via CF API without delay (de facto real time traffic values)?
Asking the CF community did not bring any results.

This is pure speculation: My guess is that CF is intentionally delaying the traffic data because they want you to pay them to handle DDoS attacks. If you can do it yourself they make themselves somewhat useless.
